# How to change the opacity of elements in css?

Tags: html, css

I could probably figure out a way to do this in JS but im wondering if theres a way to do it in CSS.

What i have is a page of elements, rectangles to be exact and on hover I want to change the `opacity` of them. Currently i have this  :

```
.rectangle:hover{
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Works great. But what i want to happen is on hover I want the one i hover over to have `opacity` full (1.0) and the rest to change to lower `opacity` (0.5). Something like this :

```
.rectangle:hover{
   opacity:1.0
      rectangle:nohover{
         opacity:0.5;
      }
}
```

I only want the `opacity` to change when on hover so setting the rectangles to have opacity 0.5 from the start is not what i need.

Comment: your question was very vague.

Comment: sorry for the typo, i thought by the second code snippet you would have guessed what i wanted :)) xo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if all the `rectangle` share a common parent.

```
#parent .rectangle {
    opacity: 0.2;
} 

#parent:hover .rectangle {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#parent:hover .rectangle:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, @ben give me a code snippet to show it, but seen as you answered first ill chose yours as the correct answer :) thanks, help a lot

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```css
.rectangle {
    width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 5px;
}
.container { float:left }
.container:hover .rectangle {
    opacity: 0.2
}
.container:hover .rectangle:hover {
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: cheers for the answer man :)) i like the code snippet too, but @magnus gave the same correct answer before you answered. Thanks again though :)))

Comment: hehe yeah :) takes a bit more time to create snippets ;)

Comment: appreciate it though ;))

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding a wrapping div.

```
.wrap:hover .rectangle{
  opacity:0.5;
}
.wrap:hover .rectangle:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: too slow :p

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
  <div class="rectangle">
</div>
```

css

```
.rectangle {
  opacity:0.7;
}
.container:hover .rectangle {
  opacity:0.5;
}
.container:hover .rectangle:hover {
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

this should do the trick, as long as all rectangles have the same parent, and there's no other objects in the container

Answer (score 0):

```
.rectangle{
   opacity : 0.5;
 }
.rectangle:hover{
   opacity : 1;
}
```